# Cant change document title on desktop with my addin

Tags: office-js, office-addins, word-addins

I am trying to modify my Word document title with my addin. Document title is one of the buildin properties and I think I can just simply access and manipulate it with one line "context.document.properties.title".

However it works only for word online but not on desktop.How can I solve this?

```
(() => {
  Office.initialize = (reason) => {
    $(document).ready(() => {
      $('#run').click(run);
      $('#ChangeProf').change(profileChanger);
      $('#updateFields').click(updateFields);
      $('#getImage').click(getImage);
      $('#contentcontrol').click(ContentControlTest);     
    });
  };

 function updateFields() {
    var newTitle = document.getElementById("inputTitle") as HTMLInputElement;
    var newOwner = document.getElementById("inputOwner") as HTMLInputElement;
    var newRevision = document.getElementById("inputRevision") as HTMLInputElement;
    Word.run(async (context) => {
      //console.log(newTitle.value);
      context.document.properties.load("title");
      context.document.properties.title = newTitle.value;
      context.sync().then(function () {//other code});
    }

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please share the actual code you are using. What you have shared doesn't provide very much for us to help with.

That said, if I'm understanding your question correctly, your scenario should be covered by something like:

```
Word.run(context => {
  context.document.properties.title = "My New Title";
  context.sync().then(() => console.log('Done!'));
});
```

Comment: Thank you @casieber for your help.I have added my code, and I can still repro the issue. On desktop, it even doesn't go inside context.sync().then(function (){...}) somehow. But works fine with word online.

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding this line just above the `context.sync`:

```
context.document.properties.title = newTitle.value;
context.document.properties.load("title");
var myTitle = context.document.properties.title;
```

In the then method, reference by the variable, instead of the Office property:

```
console.log(myTitle);
```

This code works for me in desktop and Word Online.

Comment: Thank you @Rick Kirkham, but I of course have tried load the title fisrt as well, but it doesn't help. I have been working on this for 3 days but just can't figure out which part went wrong;( I added more code, mybe you can take a look?

Comment: I added detail to my answer.

Comment: Thank you Rick, tried your code, it still doesn't work on desktop. It even doesn't run the then method. Online works fine though. Both me and my colleguage get the same result.